# Non-constant Bandgap in a semiconductor

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

For a material made of two different intrinsic semiconductors (SC); $SC_A$ on the left, and $SC_B$ on the right, such that $E_{gap,A}>E_{gap,B}$, the energy band diagram would look like so:
[image]

**Note:** It is also assumed that both semiconductors have the same effective densities of states $N_C$ and $N_V$.

As I have learned, a curve in the energy band would indicate the presence of an electric field. However, we studied only PN junctions in which the slopes of both $E_C$ and $E_V$ are the same (As in, the electric field is the same for electrons and holes).

From the band diagram above, one could conclude that there are two separate electric fields, one for the electrons and another for the holes (otherwise the slopes in the energy bands must be the same). Is this conclusion correct though? If so, why does it happen? And how can there be electric fields which interact only with one type of charges?

I would appreciate any help, or if there is some reference to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Solar Cell Device Physics](https://books.google.com/books?id=0B0aA_DFZwoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=solar%20cell%20device%20physics&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA7a-I-KfNAhUP4GMKHSKfAWEQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=solar%20cell%20device%20physics&f=false), the author Stephen Fonash makes a distinction between "electrostatic (electric) fields" and "effective fields", and you have stumbled upon an example that needs the distinction.

Electrostatic fields arise from a real electric charge density, which would be caused,for example, by uncompensated donor atoms. In your schematic as you chose both materials apparently to have the same work function(Fermi Level with respect to Vacuum Level) such that there was no charge transfer between the materials when combining them. I can tell this because the Fermi Level is centered near the junction and in the bulk. As there was no charge transfer there will be no uncompensated donor atoms, no net charge, and therefore no electrostatic field.

However you are correct that these changes in electron and hole affinities will exert effective forces on the charges. Fonash describes the total force on an electron as:

$F_e$ = -e($\xi$ - $\frac{d\chi_e}{dx}$-$k T_n\frac{dN_c}{dx}$)

Where $\xi$ is the electrostatic field, $\chi_e$ is the electron affinity (conduction band vs vacuum level), and the conduction band density of states. You can see that changes in the electron affinity, which will show up as the band bending you drew above, will cause a force on the electrons. There will be a similar equation for holes.

So yes, electrons and holes will be driven to the right. These currents will presumably be balanced by diffusion currents in the opposite direction in thermal equilibrium. This device structure would not be very useful for a solar cell as electrons and holes move in the same direction, but it is the basic structure of a heterojunction laser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, I searched the web a lot for an explanation but you have provided me with a sufficient one :)